# Django not using the form tag

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In my Django template I don't wanna use {{form]] tag. Is there any way I can save the HTML form to my models without using {{form}} tag?

**myform.html**

```
<form id="firstform" action="{% url 'saveview' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand">
  <input type="text" name="series" id="series">
  <input type="text" name="model" id="model">

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-button" name="save-button" value="SAVE">

 </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def saveview(request):

   return render(request,'myform.html')
```

Comment: Please share the relevant model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Django forms without rendering `{{ form }}` at all - you just need to make sure that your input names match the field names that the form expects. If you need more control over your form rendering then you can loop through each field like so:

```html
{% for field in form %}
<!-- access field properties, value, etc. -->
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit**
Is that all your `views.py` file contains? You need to create the form and pass `request.POST` to it for the form to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create `HTML` page only contains the Form and by using the `include` tag you can reuse it in many HTML pages

form.html

```
  <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand">
  <input type="text" name="series" id="series">
  <input type="text" name="model" id="model">
```

home.html

```
...
{% include "form.html" %}
...
```